# Cluster analysis for few data points

Tags: clustering

I have a question regarding cluster analysis.

I was wondering if I have only 9 data points, is it valid to use k-means methods in cluster analysis?

I have done a special molecular evolution analysis and it has generated 9 points, what I want to know is that whether there is any clustering among the groups. What I did was to just assign numbers to 3 groups and then do ANOVA and post-hoc t-test, but I was wondering if there is a more appropriate method for that?

Thanks.

Comment: What data have you got about these nine points?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by "points," "groups," and "numbers."  You 'have' 9 data points; the analysis 'generated 9 points'; you are interested in 'clustering among the groups'; and you 'assigned numbers to 3 groups.'  Clarification would probably bring you more answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *small* data sets, *hierarchical linkage clustering* is a good choice.

Even single-linkage may do the trick for you.

You can afford to use the most expensive clustering algorithm (most linkage variants are in $O(n^3)$) if $n=8$; it's only for really large data sets where k-means shines because of its linear runtime.

Plus, linkage clustering allows you to use a domain specific similarity, measure, whereas k-means assumes your data to be Euclidean.